# CSS float container doesn't wrap around it's children, clearing the children doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't div with class "items" wrap around its "item"s? Applying `clear: both` to the children doesn't help. The section also does not wrap around "item"s.

```css
.items {
    background: #ff0;
    width: 1000px;
    display: block;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
    width: 290px;
    height: 350px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 23px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item1">
      <h3>Php testing</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item2">
      <h3>Jquery testing</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
      <h3>Another one</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just try
    .items{overflow:hidden}

Comment: Well overflow:hidden forces the containing element to strech to encompass it's floating children as long as it has auto width and height

Comment: Btw this one also works in old borwsers like ie7 etc

Answer (score 1):

When an item is floated, it's taken out of the normal "flow" of the document so containers ignore it being there and don't wrap around it. There are several "float clearing" solutions to make the container wrap floated items. This one is the old standard:

HTML

```
<section>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item1">
            <h3>Php testing</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item2">
            <h3>Jquery testing</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item3">
            <h3>Another one</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    visibility: none;
}
```

Another option is using the CSS `:after` pseudo-element but this only works in more modern browsers:

```
.items:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    visibility: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a clearfix, an element (or pseudo-element) after the items. It's common practice to give the parent element the class "clearfix". Here's a simple pseudo-element method for the CSS:

```
.clearfix::after {
    content: ''; /* To create the pseudo-element */
    display: table; /* This is the shortest way of making it work here */
    clear: both; /* This actually pushes it below and expands the parent */
}
```

Comment: should I add it to all containers which has floated items inside, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Adding it to `.items` will make it (and section) expand.